# Newbie to C, Pointers giving error ('p1' undeclared first use in this function)

Tags: c, pointers

I've just started pointers, I have the simplest of exercises possible I am hoping I'm not just thick and it's Dev C++ that's being a tool.

this is my code (should simply printout the memory address of pointer 'p1':

```
Lab7Ex1()
{
    int integer = 100;
    char character = 'D';
    float pies = 3.14;

    p1 = &integer;
    p2 = &character;
    p3 = &pies;

    printf("\nAddress 0x%x", p1);
}
```

but despite reading through the lab notes on this over and over it still gives me an error telling me I've not declared 'p1' when I'm looking at it and 'p1' is like right there... declared.

```
p1 = &integer;
```

Comment: With all the down-votes someone should have explained the reason sooner. This is likely the result of your question being pointless. It sounds like you have a question you already have an answer to and felt like asking it anyway for unknown reasons. Hence the down-votes.

Comment: Your final comment. No you didn't fix it with `int p1 = &integer;`. It has to be `int *p1 = &integer;` as answered by @abelenky.

Comment: I honestly assumed it would help other newbies but I can take it down if you request.

Answer (score 3):

Look, you know how to declare an integer, char, and float, because you did that already.

You also have to declare Pointers too:

```
int*   p1;   // p1 is a Pointer-to-Integer. 
char*  p2;  // p2 is a Pointer-to-Char.
float* p3; // p3 is a Pointer-to-Float. 

p1 = &integer;  // Set p1 to point to a real object.
p2 = &character;// Set p2 to point to a real object.
p3 = &pies;     // Set p3 to point to a real object.
```

**Edit**

OP asks about:

```
int p1 = &integer;  // WRONG: This only declares an int, not a Pointer-to-Int.
```

The `*` is very important to making a pointer.

If you want, you can do:

```
int*   p1 = &integer;  // Create a pointer, and set what it points to on one-line.
char*  p2 = &character;
float* p3 = &pies;
```

Comment: thanks, 
i take it that declaring the pointers as you have is better than:
int p1 = &integer;
int p2 = &character;
int p3 = &pies;